# How can I dynamically assign an url to an image map?

Tags: php, variables, dynamic, imagemap

I'm trying to dynamically insert an URL in an imagemap using PHP.

1. I check if the current URL contains a substring.
   If yes the url will be ...
   If no the url will be..
2. In case there is a problem with PHP I do a check if the variable $myurl exists.
   If not assign a default value to $myurl
3. Then I insert the variable $myurl in the imagemap.

However it doesn't work.
When I move the mouse over my image map I see this as URL: `<?= $myurl ?>`
What did I wrong?

The code:

```
[1]
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/nl/") !== false){
   $myurl = "url2"
} else {
   $myurl = "url1"
}

[2]
if (!isset($myurl)) {
    $myurl = "url1"
} 

[3]
<img src="../imagemap_blue.png" usemap="#imagemap2">
<map name="imagemap2">
<area shape="rect" alt="" coords="15,5,302,55" href="<?= $myurl ?>">
</map>
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your server support the short tags? If not (perhaps you're using a version of PHP earlier than 5.4), maybe try replacing

```
 <?= $myurl ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $myurl; ?>
```

Or try setting short_open_tag to "1" if you can:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

If that doesn't work either, the standard php open/close tags aren't working correctly, and you need to figure out why that is. Make sure your file has a .php extension on the end. Make sure you have an actual server (localhost or an external one) you're opening your page on.

Comment: While plausible on the face of it, it's worth noting that if this solves the problem the OP must be using PHP 5.3 or older, [which has been out of official support for well over 6 years](https://www.php.net/eol.php)! Since version 5.4, `<?=` doesn't require that setting.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. I just see `<?php echo $myurl; ?>
` as url

Comment: short_open_tag=On

Comment: Well, just some guesses... does your file have a .php extension on the end? (Obviously the standard php open/close tags aren't working correctly, so you need to figure out why that is). I also notice that you don't have semicolons at the end of your statements in examples [1] and [2], I wonder if that's messing anything up? E.g. I would replace `$myurl = "http://www.remcon.com"` with `$myurl = "http://www.remcon.com";`. I've often had strange problems appear because I forgot to add a semicolon to the end...

Comment: The other thing I can think of is that you don't have a server running?